# AVCaptureDevice isTorchActive does not work for React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, avcapturedevice, react-native-native-module

I've tried to write my own module to detect is torch turned on/off.

According to documentation I've tried to run KVC as below

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == torchActiveObservationContext) {
        AVCaptureDevice *thisDevice = (AVCaptureDevice*)object;
        [self sendEventWithName:@"TorchEvent" body:@{@"isTorchActive": thisDevice.isTorchActive ? @"ACTIVE" : @"INACTIVE"}];
        NSLog( @"Current torch level: %f", thisDevice.torchLevel);

    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
        NSLog( @"ABCDEF");
    }
}

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog( @"Start Initialization");
        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        [videoDevice addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isTorchActive" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:torchActiveObservationContext];
        NSLog( @"End Initialization");
        // whatever other initialization code ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

But I noticed that any change is recorded if i try to turn on the torch in Control Panel. So i tried to do it much easier and check the current torch state manually. I created simple method:

```
RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(isTorchActive)
{
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCapturePhotoSettings *photosettings = [AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettings];
            
    NSLog( videoDevice.isTorchActive ? @"on" : @"off");
    NSLog( @"Level : %f", videoDevice.torchLevel);
    return videoDevice.isTorchActive ? @"on" : @"off";
}
```

But it returns "off" all the time, even if torch is initially flashed. Torch level is 0.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `videoDevice.isTorchActive` with `videoDevice.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOn` If torch was previously activated from Control Center, you can get `AVCaptureTorchModeOff`, when running this code first time.